# X uncountable implies X' uncountable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an uncountable set. So the set of limits points ($X'$) is uncountable.

I understand this intuitively but I don't know how the information "$X$ is uncountable" is useful to get informations about $X'$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Should I flag the question I found as a duplicate of your question?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I don't know honestly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every point $a\in X\setminus X'$, thee is some $r>0$ such that $B_r(a)\cap X= \{a\}$. The sets $B_{r/2}(a)$ are pairwise disjoint. Pick a rational from each $B_{r/2}(a)$. In the end, you pick $|X\setminus X'|$-many rationals.